# Angular 9 - patch value with a static object

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this patch value here,I just pass an object to this.

```
this.formPesquisar.controls['daniloTeste'].patchValue(this.dadosVisualizar.daniloTeste);
```

But I want to pass a static object, something like:

```
this.formPesquisar.controls['daniloTeste'].patchValue(2,'OBJETO');
```

How could i do this in angular 9? It's a form control patch value.

Comment: Unclear what you want and what is currently not working.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you're trying to do here... but if you want to pass object as parameter of patchValue than just use curly braces:

```
   this.formPesquisar.controls['daniloTeste'].patchValue({
       key1: 'value1',
       key2: 'value2'
   });
```

Comment: `{2,'OBJETO'}` - this is invalid object